# Java enums and Objective-C enums

Tags: java, objective-c, enums

I have the following enum in Objective-C:

```
typedef enum {
    APIErrorOne = 1,
    APIErrorTwo,
    APIErrorThree,
    APIErrorFour
} APIErrorCode;
```

I use the indexes to reference an enum from an xml, for example, `xml` may have `error = 2`, which maps to `APIErrorTwo`

My flow is I get an integer from the xml, and run a switch statement as follows:

```
int errorCode = 3

switch(errorCode){
    case APIErrorOne:
        //
        break;
    [...]
}
```

Seems Java dislikes this kind of enum in a switch statement:

[image]

In Java it seems you can't assign indexes to `enum` members. How can I get a Java equivalent of the above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One question per post is the general rule here.

But evolving the JB Nizer answer.

```
public enum APIErrorCode {

    APIErrorOne(1),
    APIErrorTwo(27),
    APIErrorThree(42),
    APIErrorFour(54);

    private final int code;

    private APIErrorCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public static APIErrorCode getAPIErrorCodeByCode(int error) {
       if(Util.errorMap.containsKey(error)) {
         return  Util.errorMap.get(error);
       }
       //Or create some default code
       throw new IllegalStateException("Error code not found, code:" + error);
    }

    //We need a inner class because enum are  initialized even before static block
    private static class Util {

        private static final Map<Integer,APIErrorCode> errorMap = new HashMap<Integer,APIErrorCode>();

        static {

            for(APIErrorCode code : APIErrorCode.values()){
                errorMap.put(code.getCode(), code);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then in your code you can write

```
int errorCode = 3

switch(APIErrorCode.getAPIErrorCodeByCode(errorCode){
    case APIErrorOne:
        //
        break;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Your enum has nothing to do with the previous answer ! Thank you this works.

Comment: Got to say this is crazy how much of an overkill this is for enums in Java, I would almost be better to have a couple of static variables...

Comment: @Daniel, I'm glad that you like the solution. But i would go with JB Nizet solution. Where in switch you call `case APIErrorOne.getCode():`. The compiler assure that you switch only one type so it is not possible to do `int e = 1 switch { case 1: break; case APIErrorCode: braek; }`.

Comment: But that doesn't work, `getCode` in both your and his examples are instance methods. But I just worked out, I would need to do: `case APIResponseErrorType.EMPTY_FIELD.getCode():` ===> Sorry that's my real code. It was very difficult to understand how his solution works but now I can see. So the `enum` declaration is much shorter then yours... I guess I'll switch back to his. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: In actual fact, I have a major problem using this kind of enum in a switch, firstly, I need to use: APIErrorCode.APIErrorOne.getCode() on his answer, but more importantly, please see my question updated with a screenshot. It looks like this is considered as a non constant expression using this indexed enum.

Comment: @Daniel, you are right, i have forgot about that i thought that `final` will do the job but it should be `const` and this is not acceptable for enums. So at the end, that extension provided by me is the solution for your problems.

Comment: I thought I was going crazy :D Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

Java enums have a built-in [ordinal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29), which is 0 for the first enum member, 1 for the second, etc.

But enums are classes in Java so you may also assign them a field:

```
enum APIErrorCode {
    APIErrorOne(1),
    APIErrorTwo(27),
    APIErrorThree(42),
    APIErrorFour(54);

    private int code;

    private APIErrorCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I set the first error ordinal 1, and leave the others unassigned? Like in Objective-C, will the indexes cascade ?

Comment: @Daniel, no you can not. If you specify a constructor all enum items must declare it.

Comment: No, you can't. Ordinals always start at 0. But you can add a method that returns ordinal() + 1.

Comment: How can I use this enum? APIErrorCode(1), APIErrorCode.get(1), APIErrorCode.code(1) ?

Comment: @JBNizet, I think that encouraging the ordinal to be used by coder is not best advice. The ordinal was used to optimize the EnumSet that was designed to replace the byte mask.

Comment: Like every other enum: `APIErrorCode.APIErrorTwo` is the instance `APIErrorTwo`. Its code is `APIErrorTwo.APIErrorCode.getCode()`.

Comment: @Daniel, you can create a field entirely unrelated to the ordinal, and manipulate, switch on, etc. that field.  But it won't get any special API support from the language.

Comment: It isn't possible to create a switch which maps an int to the enum. In fact I can't seem to use it in any way

Comment: @Daniel, you can use `case APIErrorOne.getCode():`

Comment: Please post an example, for me I am getting warning that `getCode` isn't a class method, if I change it then it can't use `this` keyword in `this.code`, if I change that to `static`, it can't be `private`. Please post a working example and I will accept the answer